# PHP FTP long filename issues?

Tags: php, ftp

I'd written a ftp script and its working fine but when it has long filesname it gives error "PHP Warning:  ftp_get(): Failed to establish connection." . I do not understand why it gives connection error.

I am using FTP PATH of 60 charecter and filename varries everytime. when filename over 25 charecter it gives connection error.

Comment: Have you try to turn on the passive mode ?